# source /etc/environment not working from bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

Running Ubuntu 18.04-x64

I run the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z $JAVA_HOME ]; then
    PLACE=`which java`
    QUOTE='"'
    VAR_NAME="JAVA_HOME="
    echo "$VAR_NAME$QUOTE$PLACE$QUOTE" >> /etc/environment
fi
source /etc/environment
```

I run `echo $JAVA_HOME` and get a blank output

If I enter the following commands in the terminal

```
source /etc/environment
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I get `/usr/bin/java` as output

Why is `source /etc/environment` not working inside the script?

Comment: Are you running `echo $JAVA_HOME` from inside the script, or from the parent shell after executing the script? The `source` command can only alter the environment of the former (unless you source the script itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could source your script instead of executing it. Then the script's `source` command occurs in your current shell.

Also, JAVA_HOME should be a directory:

```
printf 'JAVA_HOME="%s"\n' "$(dirname -- "$PLACE")" >> /etc/environment
```

that also allows you to drop the VAR and QUOTE vars

*Also*, you **must** use quotes: `[ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]`

- if JAVA_HOME is actually empty, the shell sees `[ -z  ]`
- with only a single argument, the `[` command returns true if the argument itself is *not empty*.
- Since the string "-z" is never empty, the condition is **always** true,
- and you'll get a new JAVA_HOME=... in the /etc/environment every time.

Comment: Note that `/etc/environment` does _not_ use shell syntax and the quotes might be dangerous: `X="Y"` will set X to `"Y"` (including the quotes).